# How to split names using regular expression in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My dataset looks like below. I am trying to split "2nd" column into title, First name and last name using regular expression.I am new to python and regex.

So far my code looks like below

```
def spilt_it(name):
re.findall()
if x :
return(x.group())
```

Dataset:

```
{
    'Name': {0: ' Braund', 1: ' Heikkinen', 2: ' Allen', 3: ' Moran', 4: ' McCarthy'}, 
    'Fullname': {0: ' Mr. Owen Harris ', 1: ' Miss. Laina ', 2: ' Mr. William Henry ', 3: ' Mr. James ', 4: ' Mr. Timothy J '}, 
    'num': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}
}
```

Comment: Could you add only a few lines (rows) of your dataset?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. Emphasis on *minimal*. What's showing that wall of data going to accomplish?

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: Please add an example of the end result you are looking for. Is this for the Titanic dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) you can split your `Fullname` column by space character `" "`, `n=-1` means return to all splited word. So, Full working example using `df["Fullname"].str.split(" ", n = -1, expand = True)`,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: ' Braund', 1: ' Heikkinen', 2: ' Allen', 3: ' Moran', 4: ' McCarthy'}, 'Fullname': {0: ' Mr. Owen Harris ', 1: ' Miss. Laina ', 2: ' Mr. William Henry ', 3: ' Mr. James ', 4: ' Mr. Timothy J '}, 'num': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}})

new = df["Fullname"].str.split(" ", n = -1, expand = True) 
# making seperate title column from new data frame 
df["Title"]= new[1]   
# making seperate first name column from new data frame 
df["First Name"]= new[2] 
# making seperate last name column from new data frame
df["Last Name"]= new[3]
print(df.head())
```

**Output:**

```
         Name             Fullname  num  Title First Name Last Name
0      Braund     Mr. Owen Harris     1    Mr.       Owen    Harris
1   Heikkinen         Miss. Laina     0  Miss.      Laina
2       Allen   Mr. William Henry     0    Mr.    William     Henry
3       Moran           Mr. James     0    Mr.      James
4    McCarthy       Mr. Timothy J     0    Mr.    Timothy         J
```

Comment: Please explain new=df['Fullname'].str.split(' ',n=-1,expand=True) ?

Comment: @Data_is_Power have a look on my edit. I've added the split reference also so you can easily understand what are meanings of different parametes of `split`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

**Main point:** use function `str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)`

I don't see any last name in your example, so I'm just making one split. You could make as many as you like with parameter n=1 or n=2 etc.

**First:** [strip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) some extra spaces from your names and then [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the name on the first space:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

split_names = (df['Fullname']
    .str.strip()
    .str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0:'Title', 1:'First_name'})
)
```

**Then:** add this split name to your dataframe using [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, split_names], axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)
         Name             Fullname  num  Title     First_name
0      Braund     Mr. Owen Harris     1    Mr.    Owen Harris
1   Heikkinen         Miss. Laina     0  Miss.          Laina
2       Allen   Mr. William Henry     0    Mr.  William Henry
3       Moran           Mr. James     0    Mr.          James
4    McCarthy       Mr. Timothy J     0    Mr.      Timothy J
```